# Multiple substitutions of a string in a text, without matching substrings

Tags: python, regex

I try to substitute distinct strings in a text using regex without matching substrings.

I use:

```
v = {"Anna" : 'UNNK'} 
text2 = "My name is Anna not Maria-Anna"
for i in v.keys():
    w = r"\b{}(?![-|\w*])".format(i)
    reg = re.compile(w)
text3 = reg.sub('UNK', text2) 
print(text3)
```

The code returns:

> "My name is UNK not Maria-UNK"

Where I would like to return :
"My name is UNK not Maria-Anna"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating. This could be done using just string `replace` with added space around the key and value ensuring that you replace only the whole word (not inside word):

```
v = {"Anna" : 'UNNK'} 
text2 = "My name is Anna not Maria-Anna"

text2 = f' {text2} '
for k, v in v.items():
    text2 = text2.replace(f' {k} ', f' {v} ')

text2 = text2[1:-1] 
print(text2) 
# My name is UNNK not Maria-Anna
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure we haven't a non-space before and after:

```
v = {"Anna" : 'UNNK'} 
text2 = "My name is Anna not Maria-Anna"
for i in v.keys():
    w = r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(i)
    reg = re.compile(w)
text3 = reg.sub('UNK', text2) 
print(text3)
```

**Output:**

```
My name is UNK not Maria-Anna
```

- `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind, make there is no non-space before
- `(?!\S)` negative lookahead, make there is no non-space after

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need

```
w = r"(?<= ){}(?= )".format(i)
```

Btw it's unclear for what you define the dict, as you never use the key's value...

Answer (score 0):

In example you provided you could use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\s|^)Anna(?=\s|$)
```

Explanation:

`(?<=\s|^)` - positive lookbehind: assures that what preceds is whitespace `\s` or beginning of a string `^`

`(?=\s|$)` - positive lookahead: assures that what follows is whitespace `\s` or end of a string `$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0AcF6/2)